# Jest unit test assertion fails though code is reached

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm attempting to unit test a small NodeJS application I have written with jest, but have run into some trouble with my assertions.

The code which functionality I'm attempting to test:

```js
sendData(process.env.API_HOST_DOMAIN, process.env.API_SENSORS_ENDPOINT, payload).then(() => {
  Buffer.clear();
}).catch(() => {
  Buffer.write(temps);
})
```

the sendData function is a function that does the following:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const sendData = (baseUrl, path, data) => {
  return axios.post(path, {
    'data': data
  }, { baseURL: baseUrl });
}

export default sendData;
```

Then in my unit test I try mock the axios call with

```js
axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject());

App.run();

expect(Buffer.write).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

When I run this in verbose mode with `console.log()`s placed in the catch block. I can see that it reaches that part. However the assertion still fails. It seems to me that there is something not right in the way I wrote my test, however I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out, but you should create a jest mock function from the Buffer's write method somehow like this:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(Buffer, "write");
```

Then use the `spy` mocked function in the assertion.

Comment: I have now  created a spy with `const bufferWrite = jest.spyOn(Buffer, 'write');` and the set the assertion to check on it `expect(bufferWrite).toHaveBeenCalled()` but it still tell me that the function has not been executed.